# Making share extension with custom layout

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension

I want to develop ios share extention with custom callout. In apple documents

> To provide a custom compose view instead of the standard one, deselect
>   “Use standard social compose interface” in the Xcode target-adding
>   pane. When this checkbox is deselected, the default
>   SharingViewController class is based on NSViewController or
>   UIViewController, depending on the platform you chose.

but I can't find the check box. Can anyone show me how to disable it and is there any good tutorials for share extention.

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It looks like that option was removed (or never made it to a public release).

Anyway, from reading the description, it sounds like you just need to create a share extension, and change the `ShareViewController`'s superclass from `SLComposeServiceViewController` to `UIViewController`, and get rid of the `isContentValid`, `didSelectPost`, and `configurationItems` stub methods in the class definition.

Then you can set up your view however you like in `MainInterface.storyboard`.

Comment: extensionContext is also available in the custom UIViewController since this is in UIViewController class. At first I was puzzled of how you would go about accessing it.

Comment: thanks rob. I scoured the docs as much as I could for a definitive answer on this. Was really hoping there was a method like `presentComposeView:animated:` that was included by apple. but even looking at the stack trace for the method calls and peeking at the SLComposeServiceViewController headers didn't give that impression. Annoying you can't even use the default implementation and just not present the default view via something like `self.composeView = [YourCustomView alloc] init];`

Comment: Can any one help me to know that can we use share extention container app view controller for display custom layout

Comment: How to get the shared resource(from which this activitycontroller is initiated) in this controller

Comment: For what it's worth, the apple documentation has not been updated to this effect as of the posting of this comment. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html

Comment: That document is in the “Documentation Archive” library, and Apple's official statement is “[This library is no longer being updated.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/)”.

Answer (score 2):

This answer above deserved an update. We should not change super class of `ShareViewController`, instead configure it via `configurationItems` to add configuration options via table cells.

This [tutorial](http://www.talkmobiledev.com/2017/01/22/create-a-custom-share-extension-in-swift/) show how to do it properly.

Comment: The OP want's to use a completely custom view for ShareViewController, not add options to the default one.