# iOS Custom Share Extension get content

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I want to create custom share extension and I would like to access to data that I want to share.

So as I read we need to inherit from `UIViewController` instead of `SLComposeServiceViewController` to have custom interface.

So with default interface I see this:

[image]

How can I get information from context? I mean get link I want to share, and for example image?

I know that there is some `extensionContext` in `SLComposeServiceViewController`, but in my case with custom UI I don't have it. In any case how to get that information form NSExtensionContext, because I have print out it in console and there is simple data structure, like we see in JSON or smth like this.

So the question is about getting link from context with custom UI, maybe I am on a wrong way.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I'm looking for good tutorials for custom views in share extensions as well

Comment: @Shwethascar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922118/making-share-extension-with-custom-layout I've used this recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

The default UIViewController class has an extensionContext property!